# Canvas Gauge drawn but need animation

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I made a custom canvas gauge but was wondering if there is a way we can animate the changes based on the values given from user?

Once Canvas is drawn, is it possible to put animation effect on it to move the shape object? or do I need to redraw this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating canvas is very basic, its just a question of redrawing the entire scene with the things you want to draw at a different location.

jQuery is not at all necessary, you could simply use a timer or an event to redraw the scene, but how you implement it is up to you. Take a look at [Mozilla's tutorials on the matter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations)

Comment: but can we implement this animation after click event using AJAX?